# git init - permission denied

Tags: 18.04, permissions, git

When I try `git init` I get `permission denied`. I'm new to Ubuntu. What might be the reason?

Terminal:

```
(python36) jkbielan@jkbielan:~/python/projects/leetcode-python$ git init
/home/jkbielan/python/projects/leetcode-python/.git: Permission denied
```

I tried `git init direction` and `sudo git init direction`:

```
(python36) jkbielan@jkbielan:~/python/projects/leetcode-python$ git init /home/jkbielan/python/projects/leetcode-python
/home/jkbielan/python/projects/leetcode-python/.git: Permission denied
(python36) jkbielan@jkbielan:~/python/projects/leetcode-python$ sudo git init /home/jkbielan/python/projects/leetcode-python
sudo: git: command not found
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Git wasn't installed in main environment. `python36` didn't have permissions and `sudo git init` didn't work because `git` wasn't installed.

Lines of code that helped:

```
source deactivate python36
sudo apt-get install git
git init /home/jkbielan/python/projects/leetcode-python
```

Comment: Running `sudo git init...` is a **bad idea** because then the `.git` directory is owned by user `root` and you won't be able to `git add` or `git commit` something. Never ever any files below your $HOME (`/home/jkbielan`) should belong to any other user except yourself. Run `sudo chown -R jkbielan:jkbielan /home/jkbielan` to fix this. Then you will be able to use `git` in your own $HOME directory without the use of `sudo`.

Comment: @PerlDuck Thanks for your comment. I have edited the answer.